# C++ avoid call to abstract base class's constructor

Tags: c++, c++11

Currently, I am building a library in C++ (using C++11 standards), and I am stuck on trying to figure out how to make my design more practical. I have the following abstract class `E`

```
template<typename K>
class E 
{
 public:
 virtual ~E() {};
 virtual void init() = 0;
 virtual void insert(const K& k) = 0;
 virtual size_t count() const = 0;
 virtual void copy(const E<Key>& x) = 0;
};
```

which I want to restrict users from instantiating it (i.e., be an interface). `E` has two sub-classes that implement the corresponding methods:

```
template<typename K>
class EOne : public E<K>
{
 public:
 EOne() {}
 EOne(const EOne& x) {...}
 void init() override
 {
   ...
 }
 void insert(const K& v) override
 {
   ...
 }
 size_t count() const override
 {
   ...
 }
 void copy(const E<K>& o) override
 {
   ...
 }
 private: 
     // some private fields
};
```

and `ETwo : public E<K>`, which is similar to `EOne`. Also, there is a different class `J`, which has a member `std::vector<E<K>>` that needs to be instantiated during construction:

```
template<typename K>
class J
{
 public:
     J(size_t n, const E<K>& e) : v(n, e)
     {}
 private:
     std::vector<E<K>> v;
}
```

In essence, by getting a constant reference for a `E<K>` object, I want `J`'s constructor to use the reference to instantiate all `n` objects of `v` using `e` as a template (i.e., call the copy constructor). As you can imagine, my goal is to have `e` be an object of either `EOne<K>` or `ETwo<K>`. For instance, I would make a call to `J<K>::J(size_t n, const E<K>& e)` the following way:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    EOne<std::string> e;
    J<std::string> j(10, e); // populate v with 10 copies of e
    ...
}
```

However, the above does not compile and the compiler complains that I cannot instantiate abstract class (I am using vc++ but I believe I will get the same error on other compilers as well). Therefore, my question has to do on how I can overcome this problem? Do you have any suggestions on how I can make my design more practical.

Thank you

Comment: `std::vector` is a value-based class. A `vector<E<K>>` doesn't make sense because it will store values of your abstract class.

Comment: "I want to restrict users from instantiating it" - but ... the compiler will do that for you because of the pure virtual functions - infact, you even state this later on

Comment: A `clone()` function and (smart)pointers are your friends.

Comment: `virtual void copy(const E<Key>& x) = 0` Polymorphic copy is a can of worms you don't want to open. Avoid.

Comment: Do you have Java background by any chance?

Comment: "I have the following abstract class E" -- no, you have a **template** for an abstract class.

Comment: @StoryTeller I have updated the base class `E` with a clone method that returns a `std::unique_ptr<E<k>>` and I use it inside the constructor of `J` to populate `v` by calling its move `push_back()` method. i.e., `v.push_back(std::move(e.clone())`. However, I get the same error that I cannot instantiate an abstract class. Any hints on that?

Comment: @n.m. yes, I do

Comment: Your vector should contain `std::unique_ptr<E<k>>`...

Comment: I wish there was a resource "C++ for Java programmers" but I know of nothing like that. So here's the basic bit of info: in C++ inheritance and polymorphism work **only** through pointers and references. (It's exactly the same way in Java, only they are not using these words, they use the same word "object" for objects and pointers). So you need to have a vector of pointers (prefer smart pointers) to E<K>.

Comment: @n.m. apparently that is what I ended up doing. it is much easier to have a `clone()` method in my `E` definition and create a vector of pointers to objects of the base type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is more than one approach to this.  What follows is the most complex reasonable one.  It requires lots of work in the type definitions, but leads to the cleanest "client" code that uses these types.

---

It is time to learn how to make a type regular.

An instance of a regular type behaves like a value.  C++ algorithms and container work far better with regular types than it does with abstract types.

```
template<class K>
class E_interface {
public:
  virtual ~E_interface() {};
  virtual void init() = 0;
  virtual void insert(const K& k) = 0;
  virtual size_t count() const = 0;
  virtual void copy_from(const E_interface& x) = 0;
  std::unique_ptr<E_interface> clone() const = 0;
};
```

this is basically your `E`, except I added `clone()`.

```
template<class T, class D=std::default_delete<D>, class Base=std::unique_ptr<T>>
struct clone_ptr:Base {
  using Base::Base;
  clone_ptr(Base&& b):Base(std::move(b)) {}
  clone_ptr()=default;
  clone_ptr(clone_ptr&&o)=default;
  clone_ptr(clone_ptr const& o):
    clone_ptr(
      o?clone_ptr(o->clone()):clone_ptr()
    )
  {}
  clone_ptr& operator=(clone_ptr&&o)=default;
  clone_ptr& operator=(clone_ptr const&o) {
    if (*this && o) {
      get()->copy_from(*o.get());
    } else {
      clone_ptr tmp(o);
      *this = std::move(tmp);
    }
    return *this;
  }
};
```

The `clone_ptr` is a smart pointer that is a `unique_ptr` that knows how to copy itself by calling `clone()` and `copy_from` on the stored object.  It may have some typos.

Now we write our E:

```
template<class K>
class E {
  clone_ptr<E_interface<K>> pImpl;
public:
  E() = default;
  E( std::unique_ptr<E_interface<K>> in ):pImpl(std::move(in)) {}
  E( E const& )=default;
  E( E && )=default;
  E& operator=( E const& )=default;
  E& operator=( E && )=default;
  explicit operator bool() const { return (bool)pImpl; }

  void init() { if (*this) pImpl->init(); }
  void insert(const K& k) ( if (*this) pImpl->insert(k); }
  size_t count() const { if (*this) pImpl->count(); else return 0; }
};
```

Our `E<K>` is now a value type.  It can be stored in a `vector`, copied, moved, etc.

How do we do `EOne` and `ETwo`?

First, take your existing `EOne` and `ETwo` and call them `EOne_impl` and `ETwo_impl`.  Implement a `clone()` function that does a `return std::make_unique<EOne_impl>(*this);` for `EOne_impl` and similar for `ETwo_impl`.

Then this helper:

```
template<class Impl, class K>
struct E_impl: E<K> {
  using E<K>::E<K>;
  E_impl() : E<K>( std::make_unique<Impl>() ) {}
  template<class...Args>
  E_impl(Args&&...args) : E<K>( std::make_unique<Impl>(std::forward<Args>(args)...) ) {}
};
```

gives us

```
template<class K>
using Eone = E_impl< Eone_impl, K >;
template<class K>
using Etwo = E_impl< Etwo_impl, K >;
```

and I believe your `J` and `main` code starts compiling and working as-is.

What we just did was create value-semantics `E<K>` type that contains a pImpl (pointer to implementation) pointing to a pure-virtual interface that knows how to copy itself, as well as the interface we want on an `E<K>`.

We then forwarded the interface of `E<K>` to the `E_interface<K>` for each method.  We didn't expose `copy_from` or `clone`, as those become `operator=` and our copy constructor.

To implement `E<K>`, you first implement `E_interface<K>`.  Then I wrote a helper to create a derived type from `E<K>` that implicitly uses that implementation.

Note that our `E<K>` is almost-never empty; not never-empty.  This is more efficient and simpler, but can cause problems down the road.

`E<K>` becomes a polymorphic value-semantics type.  This is a strange beast in some senses (as many languages don't support such a type), but in other senses it behaves exactly the way you'd want it to behave.

---

A similar solution in C# or Java would have the data stored in the vectors be fully garbage collected reference-semantics types, not value-semantics types.

This is similar to a `std::vector<std::shared_ptr<E<K>>` (with the note that shared pointers are not fully garbage collected).  Also note that copies of the `shared_ptr` end up being pointing to the same object, not new copies of it.

A `std::vector<value_ptr<E_interface<K>>` would also be a reasonable solution and get rid of some of the gymnastics I did in my `E<K>` and `E_impl<K>`.  In this case, you wouldn't rename `E` to `E_interface`.  You'd initialize the `vector` with

```
J<std::string> j(10, std::make_unique<EOne<std::string>>(e))
```

or somesuch.

---

Part of your problem is you have to ask yourself "what does it mean to copy an `E<K>`".  In C++ you get to answer this question yourself; depending on how you answer it, you may or may not be permitted to store it in a `std::vector`.

Comment: That is indeed an elegant (but kind of complex) solution. However, I believe your last paragraph is the main take-away. Apparently, I might be able to get away with just using an array of pointers to `E<K>` and store `EOne<K>` and `ETwo<K>` objects in it. However, it is indeed a complex question, which I can not answer concretely myself at this point (i.e., it is a project in the making..). However, I would like to thank you for your time and the effort you put to compile this answer.

Comment: @nick.katsip Dumb pointers (raw pointers) are bad things to put into `std::vector`s, as `vector`s expect their contents to be movable in sensible ways, and resource tracking gets hard.  `value_ptr` attempts to make a smart enough pointer to be copied and moved; `unique_ptr` is a move-only pointer (that doesn't let you make 10 copies of something).

Comment: So, which one would you suggest for my use-case? `value_ptr` or `unique_ptr`? When I tried to use `unique_ptr` and provide it to `std::vector::push_back()` with `std::move()` I got an error that I can't call the constructor of an abstract class. In detail, in the constructor I changed `v` to be `std::vector<unique_ptr<E<K>>>` and after I get a `unique_ptr<E<K>> p` object, I did `v.push_back(std::move(p))`. Then, the compiler gives me the error that I can't call an abstract class's constructor. Any suggestions?

Comment: @nick.katsip You can push back into a vector of unique pointers, which means that the problem you have is not fully described by your comment.  Try a sketch of that solution, and ask a new SO question about the error you are getting.  Make sure to post a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Since `std::vector<E<K>> v;` requires a static instantiation of class E, it will never compile (as you already noticed correctly). To make it work should use

`std::vector<std::shared_ptr<E<K>>> v;`

instead. It can store your objects `EOne` and `ETwo` dynamically while they can be referred with a pointed of type `E`. To add a new object to the vector you can use push_back:

```
v.push_back(std::make_shared<EOne<K>>{});
```

To cast between the types you can use dynamic and static cast functions for smart pointers e.g. `std::dynamic_pointer_cast<>()`.

Comment: Why `shared_ptr`? The default go-to smart pointer should be `unique_ptr`.

Comment: This does not answer the question: how to initialize your `std::vector<std::shared_ptr<E<K>>>` with `n` copies of `e`, `e` being a `const E<K>&`?